# How Can I extract the RTdose Dicom image to find its last slice origin?

Tags: header, transformation, dicom

I'm interested in extraction of transformation matrix from image coordinate to patient coordinate from DICOM header of a RTDOSE matrix.
I just have a RTDOSE as a single DICOM file.
When I get the imageorigin patient it seems that the origin for just the first slice is given.
How can I get the origin for the last slice?
(or maybe its better to said: I mean how can I extract this .dcm file to its separate slices?)

Any help will appreciated.
Zahra

Answer (score 0):

Grid Frame Offset Vector (3004,000c) defines the offset (in mm) for each dose slice. Combining the Image Position (Patient) (0020,0032), and the offset for the last slice you can calculate the position of the last slice. Direction of the offset is perpendicular to the plane on which the dose has been defined.

More details in chapter C.8.8.3.2 in Part 3 of the DICOM standard.

http://medical.nema.org/medical/dicom/2014a/output/pdf/part03.pdf